# Integrating Hadoop with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

So I am trying to integrate hadoop with eclipse. I tried to follow the steps answer under this question:
[how to integrate eclipse and hadoop 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911467/how-to-integrate-eclipse-and-hadoop-2-6/35911716#comment82457205_35911716)

But the problem is after copying the said .jar file to my eclipse location I don't see any MapReduce option in the Open Perspective -> Other menu. Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?

[image]

Note: My eclipse install location is different than this question/answer. Which I am hoping shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why do you need a perspective? You don't need it to submit a mapreduce job

Comment: I am totally a newbee with hadoop. Like literally just started working with it yesterday. I don't know anything about it. Blindly following tutorials here and there is my get go. But anyways, I got past this particular problem. Thanks! :)